# Is it required to add java to your path for android development

Tags: path

I was wondering if it is required to have java added to your path (environmental variables), if you are using the adt bundle and the jdk is installed.

With other words: Does java has to be added to your path to let the Android SDK & adt plugin function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using IDE (like Eclipse) then there is no need to do so.